# Am new to asp.net and vb.net.,now am trying to make a gridview of a database table

Tags: sql, image, gridview

now am trying to make a gridview of a database table named UploadProject.while selecting row of gridview display image in seperate image field by using imageurl At the time of compiling of following code image not displayed.an error occured..."incorect syntax near '='".Any body please help me to solve this problem

```
   Protected Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.SelectedRow
        lblimageid.Text = row.Cells(0).Text
        lbltitle.Text = row.Cells(1).Text
         get_Address()
         get_Image()
  End Sub

  Public Sub get_Address()
        Dim qry As String
        Try
            cn.Open()
            qry = "select (title,imageurl) from [UploadProject] where [id] = '" & lblimageid.Text & "'"
            cmnd = New SqlCommand(qry, cn)
            sdr = cmnd.ExecuteReader
            While (sdr.Read())
                lbltitle.Text = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString
                Image2.ImageUrl = sdr.GetValue(1).ToString
            End While
            cn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblmes2.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            lblmes2.Text = ex.Message
        Finally
            cn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub get_Image()
        Dim qry As String
        Try
            cn.Open()
            qry = "select title,imageurl from UploadProject where id = " & lblimageid.Text
            cmnd = New SqlCommand(qry, cn)
            sdr = cmnd.ExecuteReader
            While (sdr.Read())
                lbltitle.Text = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString
                Image2.ImageUrl = sdr.GetValue(1).ToString
            End While
            cn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblmes1.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            lblmes1.Text = ex.Message
        Finally
            cn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub getProjectDT()
        Dim qry As String
        Try
            qry = "select id,title,date from UploadProject "
            sda = New SqlDataAdapter(qry, cn)
            ds = New DataSet
            sda.Fill(ds, "UploadProject")
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            GridView1.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            cn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: please format your code...

Comment: @ Seiyria....Thanks for editing this code....

Comment: anybody help me for to solve its error...i think its bcz of my sql query...but how to solve this

Comment: is the error in the function of get_Address() or get_Image()

Comment: error in both....functions